# ActionView template error (missing partial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm encountering a weird error related to partials (happens in CI only). For some reason action view is not able to find a cached partial.

Things I've tried so far:

- updating/downgrading gems
- changing cache config in `environments`
- checking if haml templates are valid

It seems to be pretty random, like a timing/caching issue. Any ideas how to narrow it down further?

```
#<ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `_app_views_layouts__scripts_html_haml___2595795301995672650_69966270413140' for #<#<Class:0x00007f447a616578>:0x00007f4472804ab8>>
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/base.rb:274:in `_run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:185:in `block in render'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:385:in `instrument_render_template'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:183:in `render'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:357:in `block in render_partial'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:88:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:87:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:346:in `render_partial'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:317:in `render'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:65:in `render_partial_to_object'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:53:in `render_partial'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:38:in `render'
```

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel? And could a parallel test be clearing a global cache, causing  a race condition?

Comment: Yes, the tests are running in seperate nodes though, but I'll try to investigate :). Thanks!

Comment: It might be necessary to explicitly use a different cache per node, as a solution :)